# Debugging an app with computed environment variables in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables, run-configuration, 12factor

Consider an app which, in [12-factor style](https://12factor.net/config), receives its config in the form of a JSON document provided as an environment variable. The config contains secrets, so it is never stored on disk; instead, it is computed on the fly before starting the app, using something like [sops](https://github.com/mozilla/sops) or [nunjucks](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks).

I am trying to debug such an app in IntelliJ. Is there any way to run some arbitrary script before launch and provide its output to the app as an environment variable?

I will accept answers for any run config type, but an approach that works with "npm" or "Application" would be most helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

[EnvFile](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile) IntelliJ IDEA plug-in [added this option](https://github.com/ashald/EnvFile/pull/92/commits/8cf1dc245b51abe5a29a0b5b870c4686825e7d71) some time ago.

I did a quick test and don't see this option available, at least on Windows.

EDIT: found [it was only merged in the forked version](https://github.com/DanielWeigl/EnvFile/tree/script) and not available in the official plug-in. You will have to merge it manually and build the plug-in from sources.

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have a built-in feature for that, [feel free to vote for the corresponding request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-205637/Load-environment-variables-from-build-output-file).